# How often does the tribute chest restock?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Assuming there are multiple tribute chests for different factions (I only know of the one in the Thieves Guild), how long (if ever) does it take for the chests to get restocked with new items and money for the guild master?

Comment: Ever figure this out? I'm curious if my Thieves Guild Tribute chest will ever restock...the contents the first time around were a little disappointing :/

Comment: @spugsly I think the cistern needs to respawn for it to restock, so you probably have to not visit it for a couple weeks of in-game time.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is around a week or so. That's roughly the amount of time it took to restock for me, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I have came across a tribute chest below the college of Winterhold. For me, the chest was empty to start with, and it never restocked even after I checked multiple times.

Comment: It sounds like you first have to complete the quest chain to become the guild master before you will start receiving tribute.

Comment: This sounds more like the [Atronach Forge](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Atronach_Forge) offering box therefore would not be expected to respawn.

Answer (score -1):

Mine never restocked and I waited for months(in game time) I was also guild master